# Write jar output to console and log file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, logging, jar

I am writing a shell script which performs some deployment tasks by calling a jar.

I would like to keep a log of the jar output, as well as printing it to the console.

currently my jar call looks like this

```
java -jar deployer.jar -y "$deployList" -u "$username" -p "$password"
```

my log4j output is printed to the console, but is there an easy way to write output to both?

i have tried using  this at the end of the Jar call, and added echo to the command. But i can only seem to get one or the other:

```
3>&1 1>>deploy_log.txt 2>&1
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you read `man tee`?

Comment: i have just been trying to use tee. it is what i need to do. But i keep getting an empty file. is this command correct? `{jar call} | tee 2>&1 log.txt`

Comment: Ordering among redirections/pipes is important. You probably want something more like `java -jar .... 2>&1 | tee log.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by twalberg in the comments the solution was to use the `tee` command.

this jar call now prints to output and a file:

```
java -jar deployer.jar -y "$deployList" -u "$username" -p "$password" 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```